# union returns duplicate data in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, select, group-by, union

query using union returns duplicate values in column

```sql
select a.id , b.value  
from tableB b
JOIN  tableA a 
ON b.id_data = a.id_data 
JOIN tableC c 
ON b.id_data = c.id_data
WHERE b.place ='city' AND c.roll  = '20' 
UNION 
select c.id,  COALESCE(c.value, cast(c.number as text),cast(c.date as text)) 
FROM tableC c
where c.roll  = '15'
```

Expected result is below

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1 |
| 2 | data2 |
| 3 | data3 |
| 4 | data4 |

But I am getting below result

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1 |
| 2 | data2 |
| 3 | data3 |
| 2 | [null] |
| 4 | data4 |

tried using distinct for id as well still output contains duplicate id. Is there any other function to perform the above logic where i get unique id

```sql
select distinct(id) from
(select a.id , b.value  
from tableB b
JOIN  tableA a 
ON b.id_data = a.id_data 
JOIN tableC c 
ON b.id_data = c.id_data
WHERE b.place ='city' AND c.roll  = '20' 
UNION 
select c.id,  COALESCE(c.value, cast(c.number as text),cast(c.date as text)) 
FROM tableC c
where c.roll  = '15') as id
```

this query returns single column - unique id values but i need 2 columns in result set - id and values

Comment: There are no duplicates in the second result

Comment: expecting column id to return unique values

Comment: Well, a UNION does an implicit DISTINCT - but that applies to **all** columns, not just the first one

Comment: is there any way to remove duplicate id row from result set

Comment: So you have rows with same ID but different value. What's the rule to decide which ones aren't needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` removes duplicate result rows, that is, result rows where *all* columns are the same.

You can use the PostgreSQL extension `DISTINCT ON` to get what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, value
FROM (select a.id , b.value  
      from tableB b
         JOIN tableA a 
            ON b.id_data = a.id_data 
         JOIN tableC c 
            ON b.id_data = c.id_data
      WHERE b.place ='city' AND c.roll  = '20' 
      UNION ALL
      select c.id, COALESCE(c.value, cast(c.number as text), cast(c.date as text)) 
      FROM tableC c
      where c.roll  = '15') AS subq
ORDER BY id, value;
```

Comment: Important: the `ORDER BY` clause is what decides which rows get stripped from the result. Without it, you'll get arbitrary (not even random) rows.